# OpenRefine split in multiple cells

Tags: openrefine, google-refine

I have a simple table like this :

```
         id | name
         -------------------
         1 | Jack, Jeff, Win
         -------------------
         2 | Jonhy, chin
```

I want to split the cell name by *","* and want to preserve the id, so I after the split the table should look like this :

```
         id | name
         -------------------
         1 | Jack
         -------------------
         1 | Jeff
         -------------------
         1 | Win
         -------------------
         2 | Jonhy
         -------------------
         2 | chin
```

HOWEVER, if I click on *edit cell > split multiple-values* cell  the cell will be separated but the id will be blank (in the case that the cell was separated), below I gave an example that shows you how it looks like after clicking on it

```
           id | name
         -------------------
            1 | Jack
         -------------------
         null | Jeff
         -------------------
         null | Win
         -------------------
            2 | Jonhy
         -------------------
         null | chin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have done the "Split multi-valued cells" you need to then do a "Fill Down" on the 'id' column. This will have the effect of replicating the ID numbers in each of the 'null' celks created by the Split command